# open same popup one page

Tags: javascript, php, css

I want open same popup different button, that button actually same as top. I want connect with SQL as other row.

Please help me to find out the solution for this page work.

I have put some number to popup and minus quantity.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zOAI.png)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li class="item" id="snackList<?=$order['productid'] ?>">
                    <div class="picture"><img src="<?=$temp_imageurl ?>"></div>
                    <div class="producttitle"><?=$temp_producttitle ?> </div>
                    <div class="orderquantity"><?=$qty ?></div>
                    <div class="action" onclick="myFunction()">
                        <button id="myBtn" style="width:120px;height:45px;font-size : 20px;;" > Complete</button>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php }}}?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal"> 
        <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span> <br>
                <center>
                    Quantity: <input class="quan"type="number" name="quantity"><br><br><button style="width:100px;height:40px;">Submit</button>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
            btn.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want clarify the doubt, You want to update the quantity of particular order and save to database?

Comment: yes,but the problem now,other button not function just now,

Comment: The condition `if (event.target == modal)` passes exactly in an opposite case you want. The easiest way is to check, when the target is not the modal or an element inside it, if that check passes, hide the modal, else do nothing.

Comment: There's only one button in the code. what another button you want to add?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery UI. 
Add these 4 lines in head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In JS replace

```
modal.style.display = "block";
```

with

```
$( "#myModal" ).dialog();
```